# Ubuntu 15.04 ATI Radeon graphics Issue

Tags: drivers, graphics, 15.04, ati, radeon

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my Dell Inspiron with ATI Radeon HD 7730M graphics card. I was under the impression that Ubuntu will use my graphics card as default graphics device but it does not seem so.

In Details section of System setting I see the following:

```
Graphics: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile
```

But in additional drivers I see this as enabled and recommended:

```
Using X.Org X Server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati(open source, tested)
```

Output of lshw is as follows:

```
dataslayer@ds-Inspiron-7520:~$sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:c1000000-c13fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```

This says that driver is i915 which I suppose are Intel drivers.

I need some help in setting up my system to use ATI graphics card instead of Intel's graphics.

I have not installed fglrx yet and do not intend to do so unless absolutely necessary.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install AMD proprietary drivers.

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Then you will be able to switch adapters in Catalyst Control Center or in terminal by:

```
sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu
```

to AMD, or

```
sudo aticonfig --px-igpu
```

to Intel.

Comment: Is there a way around using AMD proprietary drivers?   I used them  last about a year ago and had a lot of black screens at bootup. Seemed like a kind of race condition.

Comment: You can try them now, or try `fglrx-updates` if it supports your adapter.